# Bubble chart with NextJS and highcharts-react-official

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, next.js

Short: I'm using Next-JS with the highcharts-react-official package. Need to make it work with highcharts-more, but I am unable to.

-- Longer explanation below

I am making an app with NextJS, which is mostly React. I have been using many different chart items with success, like line/spline/area/scatter/column, etc. Now I needed to add bubble charts, and thus it seems I need highcharts-more.

I tried applying HighchartsMore like this (as suggested at https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/16):

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HC_More from 'highcharts/highcharts-more'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'

HC_More(Highcharts)
```

and I have not changed the code for charts in the render method since it worked for all the other chart types:

```
class BaseChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <figure className="figure w-100">
                <HighchartsReact 
                    highcharts={Highcharts}
                    options={this.props.options}
                />
                <style jsx>{`
                    figure {
                        margin-top: 3em;
                        margin-bottom: 3em;
                    }
                `}</style>
            </figure>
        );
    }
}
```

Without the HC_More lines, I get error #17, since 'bubble' charts don't exist. However, with the lines, I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: n is not a function
    at C:\(...)\node_modules\highcharts\highcharts-more.js:8:280
    at C:\(...)\node_modules\highcharts\highcharts-more.js:11:268
    at Module../app/(...)/BaseChart.js
```

I posted about this in the official highcharts-react package (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/76), and another user followed up with this:

> I get the same thing. I'm interested to see how this resolves.
>
> The following steps make it work but it's not ideal and I would still like to have a better resolution.
>
> 1. I have to do the following imports (but comment out the HC_more callback invocation).

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts' //core
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import HC_more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more.src' //module
// HC_more(Highcharts) //init module
```

> 1. Perform an `npm start` and navigate to the page containing my bubble chart. It will crash giving me error 17 as aorsten described above:

```
Error: Highcharts error #17:
```

> 1. While React and Node are still watching, I release the previously commented out line:

```
HC_more(HighCharts)
```

> Then it works.
>
> It should work right from the start though without having to do the above steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is caused by NextJS and it is known issue: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/wiki/FAQ#i-use-a-library-which-throws-window-is-undefined

Easy fix is to place all modules inits in a if checking if Highcharts is an object or a function:

```
if (typeof Highcharts === 'object') {
    HC_More(Highcharts)
}
```

Issue on github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/76

Answer (score 1):

I use `next/dynamic` to render only-client-render code.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add an example to illustrate francis comment. But basically you can read about it in the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

Note however that the solution will exclude the component from rendering on the server side. Due to the Highcharts library only working in the browser. If someone finds a better solution feel free to tag me. :)

```
const MyChart = dynamic(() => const MyChart = dynamic(() => import("components/Shared/Charts/singleStackedBarChart"),
 { ssr: false }
);
    
// App.jsx
const App = ({ ...props }) => {
    return (<>
        <MyChart ... />
    </>);
}


// MyChart.jsx
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import highchartsAccessibility from "highcharts/modules/accessibility";
import { default as exportingHighcharts } from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
import more from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import { theme } from "./Common/globalChartSettings";

if (typeof Highcharts === "object") { // 
  highchartsAccessibility(Highstocks);
  exportingHighcharts(Highstocks);
  more(Highstocks);
}

const MyChart = ({ ...props }) => {
    const options = ...;
    
    return (
      <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highstocks}
        options={Highcharts.merge(options, theme)} <-- This was causing problems on the server side         allowChartUpdate={true}
        updateArgs={[true, true, true]}
        constructorType={"stockChart"}
        containerProps={containerProps}
        callback={(chart: any) => onCreation(chart) }
      />
    );
```